# Restsharp and relations / navigational properties in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, web-services, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp to fill some objects that are generated with MS Entity Framework with data from a webservice and that works really well. But this was just in a small test. Now i have created a few more tables in the database, with some relations, for which the Entity Framework generates navigational properties, and now RestSharp crashes. I guess this is because it's looking for that linked table data which is not in the webservice response.

Does anyone have an idea how to get by this? I like using RestSharp, but it's  unusable when it cant handle any relations/ navigational properties.

Comment: I am trying to do the same. Did you ever get a solution?

Comment: The question never got an anwser, so i added one, with what people told me over time about working with RestSharp. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this question never received an answer, i thought i'd add what several people told me over the past time. "It is a best practice to use POCO on services/clients".

So that's what i did. I wrote some plain old CLR classes to use with RestSharp and from there on i started filling/altering my own Entity Framework objects.

This seems indeed the best possible way to handle the RestSharp response.